# PyMongo check if update succeeded

Tags: pymongo

I'm trying to figure out how to check if an update succeeded. By default, does db.users.update(....) return a getLastError type? So can I do something like:

```
error = db.users.update(.....)
if error.n == 1:
  ....
```

How can I check to make sure that the update succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pymongo`'s vague docs say `update`'s return value is:

> [A document (dict) describing the effect of the update or None if write acknowledgement is disabled.](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update)

(Not explicitly stated but) this means that the return value is `lastError` (unless you use `safe=True`).